# Trouble with Google Developer Account

Tags: google-maps, google-cloud-platform

I'm developing an application which needs to connect to Maps and do some Geocode. I decided to use GoogleMaps, anyway Im about to use their tool and it ask me about set a bill account. The problem is Google offers a lot of products (Google Cloud) which I do not really want, is it possible to pay just for maps? and where I can set that?

Besides, I am also using Firebase (which I know is a google service), can I pay for this two services in a plan? or are completely different products?

Answer (score 0):

you pay as you go there... and don't pay for what you not use.

See the [Firebase Pricing](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/), for more details on the available plans.

[GCP Pricing](https://cloud.google.com/pricing/) is far more complex, due to lots of services being available.

Now I've found it, here's the new [Google Maps API Pricing](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/pricing/sheet).

Comment: I do not have problem with Firebase prices, but Im confused with Google Cloud Platform, do I have to enable bill account even If I just want to use the API for maps?

Comment: @JORGELUISQUINTEROMEDINA GCP (software-defined data-center) and Maps API are separate and has new pricing scheme... just added it to the answer; even now with USD 200 credit per month (possibly to simply the billing discounts, which where before displayed in free of charge requests).